# How to check if one file selected when using MultiSelection in matlab?

Tags: image, matlab, matlab-guide

I have a function that allow user to browse and choose some images like this

```
[filename, pathname, filterindex] = uigetfile( ...
{  '*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.png','Images (*.jpg, *.jpeg, *.png)'; ...
   '*.*',  'All Files (*.*)'}, ...
   'Choose Class 1 DataSet', ...
   'MultiSelect', 'on');
```

And I take the browsed images in a cell array

```
ChosenImages = strcat(pathname,filename);
```

Now I have a problem, if the user entered one image only, it doesn't return this image as one cell, it return each character as cell, and when I use

```
length(ChosenImages);
```

it returns the number of chars in the link!
also I tried

```
ischar(ChosenImages{1})
```

to check if one cell is a cell or not but it gives me an error too.

What can I do to check if the user chosen one image or multiple images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the `type` of the variable *filename* returned by `uigetfile` using the `class` function.

- if one file has been selected, *filename* will be of `char` type
- if more than one file has been selected *filename* will be of `cell` type
- if the user aborted the selection (by pressing "Cancel") *filename* will be of type `double`

You can define a `switch` block to handle the different types:

```
[filename, pathname, filterindex] = uigetfile( ...
{  '*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.png','Images (*.jpg, *.jpeg, *.png)'; ...
   '*.*',  'All Files (*.*)'}, ...
   'Choose Class 1 DataSet', ...
   'MultiSelect', 'on')

switch(class(filename))
   case 'double'
      disp('Selection aborted')
   case 'char'
      disp('Only one image has been selected')
      ChosenImages = strcat(pathname,filename)
   case 'cell'
      n_img=length(filename)
      disp([num2str(n_img) ' images have been selected'])
      for i=1:n_img
         ChosenImages = strcat(pathname,filename(i))
      end
   otherwise
      disp('Unexpected output')
end
```

Hope this helps.